# Reverse Engineer in an Aspectj java application

Tags: java, aspectj

How to find call hierarchy of functions and relation between objects in a written code that have Aspect-J.

this code developed by previous developer. and he/she has not write(!) any documents.

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the [Eclipse AspectJ Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/). It has an [Aspect Visualizer](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/visualiser/). There are some pretty impressive [demos of its capabilities here](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/demos/index.php). (The [Cross References View](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/xref/) is also very useful)